# How far apart can be solutions of $\varphi(m)=\varphi(n)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

In other words, I was thinking if $\varphi(m)=\varphi(n)$, can $m$ and $n$ be arbitrarily far apart?

That is, is it true that for every $w \in \mathbb N$, there exists $m,n \in \mathbb N$ such that $\varphi(m)=\varphi(n)$ and $|m-n|\geq w$?

Is this much known about Euler´s totient?

Or easily deducible?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they can be arbitrarily far apart.

Find two numbers $m_0\neq  n_0$ with $\varphi(m_0)= \varphi(n_0)$ (like $3$ and $4$). Then for any prime $p$ that divides neither $m_0$ nor $n_0$, we have
$$
\varphi(pm_0) = \varphi(pn_0)
$$
There are arbitrarily large such primes, meaning $pm_0$ and $pn_0$ can be arbitrarily far apart. For instance, $\varphi(3\cdot 1\,000\,003) = \varphi(4\cdot 1\,000\,003) = 2\,000\,006$, yet the two arguments are over a million apart.

Comment: ah, i forgot to forbid multiplicativities, but it would be unfair to do an edit of the question now

Comment: Right, forcing $m, n$ to be coprime would be a lot more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

For an arbitrarily large prime number of the form $p=2^k+1$, $\phi(p)=\phi(2^{2k})=2^k$

The two numbers are $2^{2k}-(2^k+1)=2^k-1$ apart, which can be arbitrarily large, assuming only that there are an infinite number of primes of the form $p=2^k+1$

Comment: In case you didn't know, as explained in [Fermat number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number), $p = 2^k + 1$ can only possibly be a prime if $k$ is a power of $2$. Those primes are called Fermat primes & "As of 2019, the only known Fermat primes are $F_0$, $F_1$, $F_2$, $F_3$, and $F_4$ (sequence [A019434](https://oeis.org/A019434) in the [OEIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-Line_Encyclopedia_of_Integer_Sequences))". Since "As of $2014$, it is known that $F_n$ is composite for $5 \le n \le 32$, \ldots", along with heuristic arguments, it's conjectured there are no more such primes.

Comment: @John Omelian Actually, I had come across those facts about Fermat primes before, but in thinking in one direction about the question at hand, I failed to bring to mind and appreciate the relevance of those facts. I have tipped my hand as an amateur. Thank you not just for the apt comment, but for reminding me to think more deeply before I present my thoughts.